# IIS rewrite to add a query variable to every request

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I know next to nothing about configuring IIS, but have been assigned a task to add a query variable to every request that is made through an IIS server that's being used as a Web proxy.

We look for any URL where the first path segment after the domain is a fixed string, like /bongo/ and redirect that to a back end server.  I have it working to perform redirects, but I'm pretty sure I have a lot of garbage that I don't need in the following config, which I got from another answer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<configuration> 
    <system.webServer> 
        <rewrite> 
            <rules> 
                <rule name="Route the requests for bongo Player" stopProcessing="true"> 
                    <match url="^bongo/(.*)" /> 
                    <conditions> 
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" /> 
                    </conditions> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://bongo.fse.companyinc.com/bongo/{R:1}" /> 
                    <serverVariables> 
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" /> 
                    </serverVariables> 
                </rule> 
            </rules> 
            <outboundRules> 
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1"> 
                    <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^http(s)?://bongo.fse.companyinc.com/bongo/(.*)" /> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="/{R:2}" /> 
                </rule> 
                <rule name="RewriteRelativePaths" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1"> 
                    <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^/bongo/(.*)" negate="false" /> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="/{R:1}" /> 
                </rule> 
                <preConditions> 
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1"> 
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" /> 
                    </preCondition> 
                </preConditions> 
            </outboundRules> 
        </rewrite>
        <tracing>
            <traceFailedRequests>
                <add path="*">
                    <traceAreas>
                        <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket,Rewrite,RequestRouting" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    </traceAreas>
                    <failureDefinitions timeTaken="00:00:30" statusCodes="200-299,300-399,400-499,500-599" verbosity="Warning" />
                </add>
            </traceFailedRequests>
        </tracing> 
    </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

1) I'm not even sure that I need the outbound rules.

2) The main problem that I have is that I want to always append a query variable, whether there are existing query variables or not.  I've tried too many configurations to list here, but I can't seem to always get it to append the variable when proxying.

I'd appreciate help from any IIS gurus out there.

Comment: Actually, solved this.  It was a piece of cake.  The issue is that we assumed that IIS would append the existing query string so we tried:
<br/>
`<action type="Rewrite" url="https://bingo.lms.bingoinc.com/bingo/{R:1}&abc=asd23242" />`
<br/>

In fact, it's smart enough to check if there is already a '?' and adds original query variables to the end, so this works:
<br/>    
`<action type="Rewrite" url="https://bingo.lms.bingoinc.com/bingo/{R:1}?abc=asd23242" />`